# DynamoDB - Create query with OR statement on hashKey and GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have DynamoDB table created with following settings:

- field `IP` as my hashKey
- field `createdAt` as my sortKey
- field `email` as GSI, index `emailIndex`, with `createdAt` as it's sort key.

How the table was designed can be changed. The requirements are that IP can be duplicated (few items in table can have same IP), email can be duplicated, but pair IP+createdAt or email+createdAt is unique.

I would like to create a function that given 2 parameters (IP and email) would return all items that have given email OR have given IP.

I've already found a way do accomplish this with `scan`, following code in Java works well

```
        ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
                .withTableName(tableName)
                .withFilterExpression("IP = :ip or email = :email")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(
                        Map.of(
                                ":ip", new AttributeValue(ipAddress),
                                ":email", new AttributeValue(email)
                        )
                );
        var result = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
```

But I don't want to use `scan`, due to it's performance - I'd prefer to use `query` (or any other function) and utilize hashKey IP & GSI email to avoid scanning table from start to finish. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two queries, not one. One request to your base table for the IP, and the other to your index for your email. 2 queries in parallel will be fast and efficient, but you may have some duplicate items as you mentioned.

If you want to do it in a single request then you'd need to use Scan and as you stated it's not efficient.